# wxpython textctr How I change some text style?

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I have the follow problem I have a textctrl and I want some text be different, for example I want text which end's with ':' char to be bold . I need to know if I can by anyway change only this text , I searched but I don't find a clear answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look up `wx.Font()`

```
MyTextCtrl.SetFont(wx.Font(9, family = wx.DEFAULT, style = wx.NORMAL, weight = wx.BOLD, faceName = 'Consolas'))
```

Although this works for all of the text within the `wx.TextCtrl()`, so the bold/normal decision would have to made by your code using variables to manage `wx.Font()`

Comment: I already know how to change font but, I dont know how to access first position of text I need to modify and last positions and apply the font in that range I'm sorry if it seems like a stupid question

Comment: Read up on `richtextctrl` https://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.richtext.RichTextCtrl-class.html

Comment: The regular `wx.TextCtrl` is also able to handle setting custom attributes on subsets of the text.  See the example in the demo and also the docs for `wx.TextCtrl.SetStyle` and `wx.TextAttr`.